# Trying to access reactive form in services

Tags: angular

I want forms in services, so that I can reuse it. I will be able to share multiple modules. So for this requirement I am trying to execute the below code. But it is showing error. Please clarify.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

@Injectable()
export class UserForm {    
    constructor(private fb : FormBuilder) {        
       return this.fb.group({ "name" : "", "email" : "" });    
    }
}
```

I got the below error:

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(28,25): error TS2554:
>       Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.src/forms/user.form.ts(7,9):
>       error TS2322: Type 'FormGroup' is not assignable to type 'UserForm'.
>       Property 'fb' is missing in type 'FormGroup'.src/forms/user.form.ts(7,9): error TS2409:
>       Return type of constructor signature must be assignable to the instance type of the class

.

How to fix the above error? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.